# Counting the number of arrangements of three different colours

Tags: combinatorics

Given $a$ red balls, $b$ blue balls, and $c$ yellow balls. There are $\binom{a+b+c}{a,b,c}$ ways to arrange them. For each arrangement, let $N$ be the number of ways to extract 3 balls of 3 different colours so that their order from left to right is: red, blue, yellow. 
I want to count the number $N_k$ of arrangements such that $N=k$.

For example, if $a=b=c=1$ then there are 6 arrangements: RBY, RYB, BRY, YRB, BYR, YBR. In this case $N_1=1$ (RBY) and $N_0=5$ (5 other arrangements). If  $a=2, b=c=1$ then there are 12 arrangements and $N_2=1$ (RRBY), $N_1=2$ (RBRY, RBYR), $N_0=9$ (9 other arrangements).

Consider a similar problem but we are given only $a$ red balls and $b$ blue balls, let $M$ be the number of ways to extract 2 balls so that their order is: red$\to$blue, let $M_k$ be the number of arrangements such that $M=k$. I can calculate the generating function of $(M_k)$. It is $\binom{a+b}{a}_q$ (q-analogue of binomial coefficient) because each arrangement with $M=k$ corresponds to a lattice path from $(0,0)$ to $(a,b)$ that enclose an area of $k$ below the path. [Gaussian binomial coefficients, lattice paths, and vector spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399127/gaussian-binomial-coefficients-lattice-paths-and-vector-spaces)

So I tried to generalize from this. But I failed. I guessed the generating function $\binom{a+b+c}{a,b,c}_q$ but it is a polynomial of degree $ab+bc+ca$ whereas the maximum value $N$ can get is $abc$.

Is there any other way to calculate the generating function of $(N_k)$?